# iframe size stays the same after go to another webpage

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I'm using phonegap to make a iPhone app and have a problem with html/javascript. I have an iFrame in my index.html to show a third-party website. My problem is when the user clicks a link in the start page of that website and goes to another webpage, the iFrame size stays the same as when it has the start page. So if the new page is shorter than the start page, there's a blank area down there. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: a quick google for "auto-resize iframe" yields a ton of answers to your problem.

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189973/iframe-auto-resize

Comment: Hi Sean, I think most of them have different use cases. What they do is they invoke a javascript function in iframe onload method which does the resizing. However, in my case iframe itself is not updated, only the webpage inside is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [onload event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_frame_onload.asp) of that iframe. It gets fired every time a page has been completely loaded inside the iframe. You can try [this easy example](http://jsfiddle.net/45HKA/). It alerts on every reload. Just click a link inside the iframe to see the alert box.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function load()
{
    alert("Iframe is loaded");
}
</script>
</head>

<iframe onload="load()" src="whatever">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```